# Take current diff from master and turn it into a single commit without applying each commit on top of each other

Tags: git

I'd like to take some branch that is X commits ahead of master, and basically snapshot the current diff and create a single commit out of it.

Normally I use `git rebase -i`, squash all the commits except for the latest one, and that works.

However, if there were conflicts or issues with the rebase halfway through that were fixed, I have to manually go through it. I don't necessarily want to apply each commit on top of each other - rather, I'd like to take the current diff between HEAD of my branch and master, and create a single commit out of it.

I've done it by manually diffing the entirety of my branch and master, creating `mychanges.diff`, then applying that to a clean branch, but it feels like there should be a native, clean way within git to not rebase by applying each commit, but rather snapshot the current state and create a single commit of the differences from master.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you want is `git merge --squash`:

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash otherbranch

[resolve any conflicts if necessary, then]

git diff --cached     # to see what you're about to commit
git commit            # to make a single non-merge commit on master
```

#### Longer

A diff is not a snapshot, so there's a fundamental mismatch here.  Let me try the old temperature analogy.  Suppose I tell you that today, it is ten degrees warmer here than yesterday.  (Though actually it's about the same :-) )  Now I have a question for you: what temperature is it today?  Or, equivalently, what temperature was it yesterday?

A *snapshot* is an absolute.  If I tell you that it is 68˚F / 20˚C, *and either* that this is 10˚F warmer than yesterday, or that it was 58˚F yesterday, those *two* pieces of information suffice.  One snapshot, or one diff, is not enough: you need two snapshots, or one snapshot and a diff.  (Note that an infinite number of diffs is never enough: you always need at least one snapshot in the sequence *somewhere*.  Otherwise there might be something that was however it was at the start, and has never changed, and you won't see it at all.)

I think what you are describing, though, is a situation like this:

```
           C--D--E--F--G   <-- branch
          /
....--A--B--H   <-- master
```

or even just:

```
           C--D--E--F--G   <-- branch
          /
....--A--B   <-- master
```

In both of these situations, you can:

- compare the snapshot in `B` vs that in `G`, which gets you a *set of changes* to convert `B` to `G`; and then
- apply those same changes to the snapshot in `H` if it exists, or to the snapshot in `G` if `H` does not exist.

Now, if `H` does not exist at all, this kind of "apply the changes" thing is entirely trivial.  The result is the snapshot in `G`.  In this case you could just copy the snapshot of G to a new snapshot—let's call it `G'` rather than `H` to help remind us that it exactly matches `G`—using some hypothetical Git command<sup>1</sup> that does just that.  The result would be:

```
           C--D--E--F--G   <-- branch
          /
....--A--B--G'  <-- master (HEAD)
```

But if `H` *does* exist, you presumably want to *combine* the changes of `B`-vs-`G` with those of `B`-vs-`H`, so that you don't wipe out the effect of the changes you made when you made `H` in the first place.  The command that combines these changes is `git merge`.

A *normal* and *full* merge, which you'd get with `git checkout master; git merge branch`, would:

- find the merge base, which in this case is commit `B`;
- diff the merge-base commit against the current branch tip `H` to find "our" changes;
- diff that same merge-base commit against "their" (still ours, but `--theirs` during the merge) commit `G` to find "their" changes; and
- attempt to combine those changes.

If there are merge conflicts, this normal merge stops and makes you finish the job.  If not, this normal merge makes a new commit with *two* parents:

```
           C--D--E--F--G   <-- branch
          /             \
....--A--B--H------------M   <-- master (HEAD)
```

We'll skip over the concept of what Git calls a *fast-forward merge* (which is not a merge at all) and go straight to what `git merge --squash` does.

When you add the `--squash` option, you tell Git to do two things:

1. Stop after the combining step, even if the combining works.  (You can get this same effect, without item #2, using `git merge --no-commit`.  If the normal merge would stop with a conflict, this squash merge also stops with a conflict too, so this is *exactly* the same as the `--no-commit` flag.)
2. When you, the user, *finish* the merge, by running `git commit`, Git will make, not merge commit `M`, but instead squash commit `S`:

   ```
              C--D--E--F--G   <-- branch
             /
   ....--A--B--H------------S   <-- master (HEAD)
   ```

   The key difference between `M` and `S` is that `S` points back to commit `H` *only*, and not to commit `G` at all.  (The default commit message text for `S` is different as well, but since you get a chance to replace this text when `git commit` opens your editor on the commit message, that difference is not really important.)

If commit `H` does not exist, the `git merge --squash` operation still does exactly this same process.  The merge base is still commit `B`:

```
           C--D--E--F--G   <-- branch
          /
....--A--B   <-- master (HEAD)
```

so the two diffs are:

- `B` vs `B`, to see what we changed: nothing, of course; and
- `B` vs `G`, to see what they changed: everything needed to cause the next snapshot to look like commit `G`, of course.

By combining these two diffs and making new commit `S`, we get a commit that matches `G`, that we can call `G'` if we prefer but I'll still call `S`:

```
           C--D--E--F--G   <-- branch
          /
....--A--B--S   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Note that after using `git merge --squash` like this, the branch `branch` should almost certainly just be killed-off entirely.  You should not go back to it and make more commits *unless* you strip commit `S` away from `master`.

(You might wonder why `git merge --squash` stops first.  The only sensible answer is that it was a historical accident whose behavior has been preserved since then.  If it didn't stop by default, you could run `git merge --squash --no-commit` whenever you *did* want it to stop.  But the first implementation of squash-merge worked by having `git merge` exit early, just before it ran its own internal `git commit`.  It was easier to code that way.  The conflicted merge and `--no-commit` cases do one more step, which is to record that the merge is in progress in an internal state file; *then* they exit.  When you run `git commit`, Git either notices the "merge in progress" state file, or doesn't, based on whether `git merge` created it.  It then either makes a normal non-merge commit, because there was no recorded state, or a merge commit, because there was recorded merge state.)

---

<sup>1</sup>There are multiple Git commands that can achieve this result.  There's no one single command that does it in one step: it takes at least two Git commands to make this happen.  That's true even with `git merge --squash`.